# probability that the ratio of remaining red cards in a deck reaches m/n at some point while dealing

Tags: probability

I think I have found a weird proof that if you are dealing cards from a deck, the probability of reaching a state where the ratio of remaining red cards is 2/3 or greater, is less than 3/4.  (And can be generalized to other ratios and other decks.)  I am wondering if (a) the proof is valid, and (b) if so, is there a simpler way of proving the same result.

The motivation was a brainteaser which asks: Suppose your friend is turning over cards from a face-down shuffled deck, and at any point you can call "Next", and if the next card is red, you win a prize.  Trivially, if you just call the first card, your chances of winning are 1/2.  Can you devise a strategy that does better than 1/2 -- for example, waiting until there are slightly more red cards remaining and *then* calling "Next", even though you might never reach a state where there are slightly more red cards?  (Read no further if you want to try and solve this brainteaser before proceeding.)

The answer is that since the deck is randomized, when you call "Next", it doesn't matter *which* remaining card is turned over next.  So the problem can be restated such that when you call "Next", you just turn over the last card in the deck, which obviously means your odds of winning are 1/2 no matter what "strategy" you use.

But it seems this fact can be used to prove some non-trivial results.  Suppose your "strategy" is to wait until the ratio of remaining reds in the deck is at least 2/3, then call "Next", unless you never reach the 2/3 ratio and you're forced to take the last card.  *Given* that you have reached at least 2/3, your chances of winning are actually greater than 2/3, because you might jump from the ratio being less than 2/3 (7 reds and 4 blacks remaining) to greater than 2/3 (7 reds and 3 blacks remaining).

On the other hand, if you never reach the 2/3 ratio, then you lose.  (In particular, if the last card is red, then you've "reached the 2/3 ratio" before that card is turned over, so you'd call "Next" on that card.  So "never reaching the 2/3 ratio" means you go all the way to the last card and it's black and you lose.)

This means
P(winning) =
P(reaching a ratio of at least 2/3 at some point) x (2/3 plus some small delta)
+ P(never reaching the 2/3 ratio) x 0

But we know P(winning) = 1/2.  So it follows that
P(reaching a ratio of at least 2/3 at some point) < 3/4

More generally, by the same logic, suppose the ratio of red cards in a randomized pile is a/b, then if c/d > a/b, the odds of dealing the cards and reaching a point where the ratio of remaining red cards is c/d, is strictly less than ad/bc.  (Of course, if c/d < a/b, then your odds of "reaching" that ratio are 100% since that's the starting condition.)

Is this valid?  And if so is there an easier way or proving the same thing?